# Return empty string instead "null" in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have create Wcf service point that returns json.
And my question is how to return empty string in json instead null.

```
{
 "Avatar": null // send only -> ""
 "Email": null,
 "FirstName": "John",
 "ID": 1,
 "LastName": "Travolta",
 "NickName": null,
 "Password": null
}
```

-------EDIT---------

```
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(_email) ? "" : _email; } set { _email = value; } }

    private string _email;

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
 "Avatar": EmptyIfNull(null),
 "Email": EmptyIfNull(null),
 "FirstName": "John",
 "ID": 1,
 "LastName": "Travolta",
 "NickName": EmptyIfNull(null),
 "Password": EmptyIfNull(null),
}

private string EmptyIfNull(string source)
{
    return source ?? String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have edit my question and add datacontract that i have. How you could see i have auto generated properties. And my question was if Wcf doesn't have some global property to make it? | In email field i have implemented your code for test.

Comment: No, of course not. That's a very unusual request (to say the very least). How about: if you don't have nulls in your source data, you won't have nulls in your JSON.